# Writing test method on List<SelectOption>

Tags: unit-test, test-setup

What is the best practice when it comes to writing a test code, should I just write code on just to make sure its returning the correct size? and also check the getValue and label is returning property?

```
public List<SelectOption> getleadsources{ 
                Schema.DescribeFieldResult leadPickList =Lead.Leadsource.getDescribe();
                List<Schema.PicklistEntry> leadsourceList= leadPickList.getPicklistValues();
                getleadsources = new List<SelectOption>();
                for( Schema.PicklistEntry le:leadsourceList){    
                    getleadsources .add(new SelectOption(le.getLabel(), le.getValue()));
                    return getleadsources;
                } 
            return null;  

    }
```

I have the following Test code but I'm not sure if this is enough:

```
@isTest static void loadAllType() {
        List<SelectOption> so = employee_CtrlExt.getleadsources(); 
        Test.startTest();     
        System.assertEquals(16, so.size());
        Test.stopTest();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your unit test should be failing; the return inside the loop terminates it after the first iteration. Secondly, if you ever change your picklist, your unit test will fail.

At minimum, I suggest these fixes:

```
public List<SelectOption> getleadsources{
    get { 
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult leadPickList =Lead.Leadsource.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> leadsourceList= leadPickList.getPicklistValues();
        getleadsources = new List<SelectOption>();
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry le:leadsourceList){    
            getleadsources .add(new SelectOption(le.getLabel(), le.getValue()));
        } 
        return getleadsources;
    }
}
```

And for the unit test:

```
@isTest static void loadAllType() {
    Test.startTest();     
    List<SelectOption> so = employee_CtrlExt.getleadsources(); 
    System.assertEquals(Lead.LeadSource.getDescribe().getPicklistValues().size(),
                        so.size());
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Finally, you can avoid doing this more than once by using "lazy loading."

```
public List<SelectOption> getleadsources {
    get { 
        if(getleadsources == null) {
            getleadsources = new List<SelectOption>();
            for(Schema.PicklistEntry le: 
                 Lead.Leadsource.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()) {    
            getleadsources.add(new SelectOption(le.getLabel(), le.getValue()));
        } 
        return getleadsources;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks for suggestion, I was just giving you an example of checking the size(), is that all you will do when you write a test code for the `getLeadSources` ? method

Comment: @NickKahn If you were really concerned about it, I'd suggest checking one of the values, but checking all of them would be overkill. It's not like the system will magically return different data for one of the values. I've always said that we shouldn't be testing system functionality, because it serves no purpose. However, the first check, making sure we return enough items, is important, because, as I've demonstrated, you would have had an uncaught logic bug if you hadn't.